# linux system both on /dev/sda and /dev/sdb

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I've got several new servers and the guy from computer shop kindly installed the ubuntu 16.04 on the servers, however, I found that one of the servers had weird partition as below.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G  4.0K   32G   1% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G  2.0M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/sdb1       1.8T  273G  1.4T  17% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             32G     0   32G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

and

```
$ fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2367df07

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   366137343   183067648   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       366139390   500117503    66989057    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       366139392   500117503    66989056   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3bb8f201

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048  3773046783  1886522368   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2      3773048830  3907028991    66990081    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sdb5      3773048832  3907028991    66990080   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Other servers have the partitions of linux systems only on `/dev/sda` which is SSD, however, this one seems that linux is mounted on `/dev/sdb` but there're also partitions with linux system on `/dev/sda`.

What I want to do is mounting linux systems just on `/dev/sda` and using `/dev/sdb` as just for saving data or other backup files.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You've got two disk on your server, and the Ubuntu has been installed on the first partition of the second disk: `/dev/sdb1`.

The word "Linux" which you see in front of `/dev/sda1` is just the type of partition:

> `/dev/sda1   *        2048   366137343   183067648   83  ***Linux***`

It doesn't have anything to do with which type of operating system has been installed on that specific partition, it might be empty or even haven't been formatted at all.

What I can suggest is to use a tool like `rsync` to move (clone) your root file system on `/dev/sda1`, there are different guide to do this:

[Easiest way to move a Linux setup to another partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/249113/easiest-way-to-move-a-linux-setup-to-another-partition)
[how to copy entire linux root filesystem to new hard drive on with ssh and tar](https://superuser.com/questions/594203/how-to-copy-entire-linux-root-filesystem-to-new-hard-drive-on-with-ssh-and-tar)
[How to move Linux to another partition?](https://serverfault.com/questions/306538/how-to-move-linux-to-another-partition)

Answer (score 0):

*If* the system hasn't been used much (that is, doesn't yet have much in the way of a customized configuration or user data on it), re-installing may be the easiest way to fix the problem. Moving the installation, as Ravexina suggests, is likely to be trickier for a newbie than re-installing; but it's probably the better option if you've already invested time in customizing the installation or if you've already stored lots of data on the system.

Be aware, too, that if your `/dev/sda` is an SSD and `/dev/sdb` is a regular hard disk, there are numerous strategies and techniques for using the two together to customize performance. Which of these strategies and techniques is best depends on how you intend to use the server. The simplest is just to mount a partition from `/dev/sdb` somewhere and store files there that don't need the best speed, leaving the main OS installation and smaller number or size of files that *do* need extreme speed on the `/dev/sda` SSD. You might also look into [bcache,](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/Bcache) which is a way to use the SSD as, essentially, a huge cache for the hard disk. This results in performance that approaches SSD levels for the entire hard disk. Bcache is harder to set up, though.

Given the mixup on the server you've written about, you may want to check the configuration of the first server to see how it's set up, both to be sure that your big hard disk is accessible and that it's configured in a sensible way for you.